# Qual a lógica por trás do switch case no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, switch

Comecei meus estudos em JavaScript e tive contato com o `switch`, segue exemplo:

```
let permissao;
switch (permissao){
    default:
    console.log('sem acesso');
    break;
    
    case 'estagiário':
    console.log('acesso limitado');
    break;

    case 'contratado':
    console.log('acesso pleno');
    break;

    case 'gerente':
    console.log('acesso irrestrito');
    break;
}
```

Pelo o que eu entendi, o `switch` funciona como uma cadeia de `if`s simplificada. Então, por que é necessário o uso do `break`?

Penso que se os cases são instruções de execução para uma situação específica, se a situação não cumpre o `case`, não deveria ser executada, tal como um `if`. Mas se tiro os `breaks`, ele roda como se todas as situações fossem verdadeiras, o que não é verdade. Qual a lógica por trás disso?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como funciona o switch por baixo dos panos?](/q/176675/112052) | [Break e Continue no Switch](/q/318636/112052) | [A última instrução de um switch precisa de 'break'?](/q/45641/112052) (apesar de não serem especificamente sobre JavaScript, esse comportamento do `switch` é comum à várias linguagens - provavelmente é mais uma "herança" do C, e uma "pegadinha" comum dessas linguagens)

Comment: Um erro repetido constantemente em muitos sites é a comparação do `switch` com IFs. São mecanismos completamente diferentes quando implementados corretamente. o `switch` é como um `goto`, ele vai para o `case` indicado e continua dali em diante (inclusive em outros `case`s). Quando você não quer que continue no `case` seguinte, você usa o `break`. Ou seja, é o programador que está usando o  `break` para deixar parecido com `if`, o que nem sempre é desejável.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É uma característica da linguagem cada `case` poder ter `break`. É assim que a linguagem foi desenhada. Quando um `break` for invocado o `switch` é interrompido.

O `case` é um [*label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), funciona como um ponteiro para o *statement* onde vai correr código para o caso específico. EM JavaScript *labels*  não bloqueiam o código, por isso é possível correr código dentro de vários labels até um `break` os parar.

Tendo dito isso, a ausência de `break` no `switch` não é erro de sintaxe mas causa comportamentos indesejáveis. Como está referido na MDN: _"a ausência do `break` vai fazer o script correr o código de "case" em "case" até encontrar um `break` ou o `switch` terminar.

> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next statement in the switch statement.

Mesmo no caso do ultimo `case` que tecnicamente não precisaria de um `break`, é preferível ter sempre por consistência e para evitar comportamentos aberrantes difíceis de debugar.

```js
const permissao = 'estagiário';

switch (permissao){
    default:
    console.log('sem acesso');
    break;
    
    case 'estagiário':
    console.log('acesso limitado');
    // break; 

    case 'contratado':
    console.log('acesso pleno');
    // break;

    case 'gerente':
    console.log('acesso irrestrito');
    break;
}
```

Comment: "É uma característica da linguagem cada case ter o seu break" - Isso está incorreto. O `break` é opcional. Ele só deve ser usado quando não há interesse em se continuar no `case` seguinte. Existem muitas situações onde é desejável a cascata (a mais comum é você atender vários cases com o mesmo código, mas não se restringe a isso)

Comment: @Bacco concordo, o que eu quero dizer com isso é que a cada `case` pode associar-se um `break`. Na resposta reforço que é opcional, mas não pode (pelo menos não tem efeito) ter 2 `break` para o mesmo `case`.

Comment: Não tem efeito somente por não chegar nunca no 2o `break`, afinal qualquer `break` provoca saída. O `break` aí é mecanismo do `switch`, não do `case`. O `case` é praticamente uma jump-list para determinar o ponto de entrada, apenas isso.

Comment: @Bacco ok, já percebi o que querias dizer como _incorreto_: ou seja eu associar que o `break` existe como uma "tag para fechar o `case`". Sim, nesse sentido tens razão e é incorreto. Vou clarificar.

Comment: Complementando, um exemplo muito comum (usei strings só pra ilustrar) onde é desejável não usar break: `case 'UP':` `case 'LEFT':` `case 'SHIFT TAB':` `fichaAnterior();` `break;` - ou seja, qualquer uma das teclas deve executar `fichaAnterior()`, não tem porque repetir código. A cascata não é efeito colateral, é um mecanismo desejável. Só é efeito colateral quando se usa o `switch` no lugar de `if`, mas novamente, é uma opção do programador, e não a filosofia do construct em si.

Comment: @Bacco, seria correto afirmar que o break é um mecanismo "do" switch? O mesmo pode ser usado em loop e em outras estruturas também.

Comment: @SpencerMelo no atual contexto ele é mecanismo do switch, não do case. Em outros contextos também tem break, mas não é relevante pro ponto em questão. O fato aqui é que a estrutura que ele está quebrando é o switch. Da mesma forma, um `while` com `if (...) { break }` o `break` é do `while`, e não do `if`.

Comment: Certo, então posso assumir que, sem algum label, ele vai ser da estrutura de loop ou switch "acima"?

Comment: @SpencerMelo justo o contrário. Se fosse do `case`, que tem o label, você poderia assumir isso, mas como é do próprio `switch` e o `switch` está presente, ele vai sair do `switch`. Não que mude a situação, mas pra ser sincero, sequer testei switch vazio pra ver se o JS aceita. Capaz que nem seja possível.

Comment: Certo, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

É assim que funciona:

1. A expressão do comutador é avaliada uma vez.
2. O valor da expressão é comparado com os valores de cada caso.
3. Se houver uma correspondência, o bloco de código associado será executado.
4. Se não houver correspondência, o bloco de código default é executado.

Se reparar, no ponto 2. ele executa **todos** os blocos. Daí ser necessário o break, para garantir que apenas executa o pretendido.

Source:https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: Sabes a razão porque a ausência do `break` faz com que os `case` seguintes validem `true`?

Comment: Sim, obrigado pela resposta mais completa! Vai ajudar o yoyo

Comment: Switch Case é equivalente a `goto`, não é como um `if`. Não existe essa comparação com cada caso, apenas se localiza a correspondência e o código segue o fluxo dali em diante.