# CASE do SWITCH não está funcionando como esperado

Tags: javascript

Fiz esse código em JavaScript, mas está saindo o mês como de dezembro e não o correto que é fevereiro.

```
function getDataPorExtenso() {
    var data = new Date(),
        dia = data.getDate().toString(),
        diaF = (dia.length == 1) ? '0' + dia : dia,
        mes = (data.getMonth() + 1).toString(), //+1 pois no getMonth Janeiro começa com zero.
        mesF = (mes.length == 1) ? '0' + mes : mes,
        anoF = data.getFullYear();

    switch (mesF) {
        case "01":
            mesF = "Janeiro";
        case "02":
            mesF = "Fevereiro";
        case "03":
            mesF = "Março";
        case "04":
            mesF = "Abril";
        case "05":
            mesF = "Maio";
        case "06":
            mesF = "Junho";
        case "07":
            mesF = "Julho";
        case "08":
            mesF = "Agosto";
        case "09":
            mesF = "Setembro";
        case "10":
            mesF = "Outubro";
        case "11":
            mesF = "Novembro";
        case "12":
            mesF = "Dezembro";
    }

    return "São Paulo, " + diaF + " de " + mesF + " de " + anoF;
}
```

Comment: Cada `case` deve ter um `break`, caso contrário o `switch` continua executando os demais (o chamado *fall through* - veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176675/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318636/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/463933/112052))

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a documentação da expressão condicional [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#description) a instrução opcional [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) associada com cada [`case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#syntax) garante que o programa saia da condicional `switch` assim que a instrução correspondente for executada e executa a instrução que segue logo após o `switch`. Caso `break` seja omitido, o programa continua a execução para a próxima instrução dentro de `switch`.

```js
function getDataPorExtenso() {
    var data = new Date();
        dia = data.getDate().toString();
        diaF = (dia.length == 1) ? '0' + dia : dia;
        mes = (data.getMonth()).toString(); 
        mesF = (mes.length == 1) ? '0' + mes : mes;
        anoF = data.getFullYear();

    switch (mesF) {
        case "00":
            mesF = "Janeiro";
            break;
        case "01":
            mesF = "Fevereiro";
            break;
        case "02":
            mesF = "Março";
            break;
        case "03":
            mesF = "Abril";
            break;
        case "04":
            mesF = "Maio";
            break;
        case "05":
            mesF = "Junho";
            break;
        case "06":
            mesF = "Julho";
            break;
        case "07":
            mesF = "Agosto";
            break;
        case "08":
            mesF = "Setembro";
            break;
        case "09":
            mesF = "Outubro";
            break;
        case "10":
            mesF = "Novembro";
            break;
        case "11":
            mesF = "Dezembro";
            break;
    }

    return "São Paulo, " + diaF + " de " + mesF + " de " + anoF;
}

console.log(getDataPorExtenso())
```

Outra maneira de obter o mesmo resultado com um código mais compacto é fazer o uso do método [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) que retorna uma string com a representação de parte da data baseando-se no idioma.
Passe como argumento `"pt-BR"` para indicar as convenções de idioma e cultura cujo quer o retorno e em opções `{dateStyle: "long"}` indicando que quer a data por extenso menos o dia da semana.

```js
function getDataPorExtenso(cidade = "São Paulo") {
  var data = new Date().toLocaleDateString("pt-BR", {
    dateStyle: "long"
  });
  return `${cidade}, ${data}`;
}

console.log(getDataPorExtenso());
```